# Select COUNT with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
project (id, name)
list (id, name, project_id)
```

I wanna get every project and number of list into the project.

I've tryed:

```
SELECT project.id, project.name, COUNT(list.id) AS list_count
FROM project 
INNER JOIN list ON (list.project_id = project.id)
GROUP BY project.id DESC
```

But I get only the project that have list.

If the project don't own list, I don't get it...

I want list_count = 0 if COUNT(list_id) = 0, how must I do please ?

Answer (score 5):

Use left join instead of Inner join

```
SELECT project.id, project.name, COUNT(list.id) AS list_count
FROM project 
Left JOIN list ON (list.project_id = project.id)
GROUP BY project.id DESC
```